# Questions about tail -c

Tags: shell, sh, tail

When I open my terminal and input the command `echo 987654321 | tail -c3`, the output is `21`.

However, when I create a file named `test_tail.sh`, write `987654321` into the file, the command `tail -c3 test_tail.sh` prints `321`.

Why these different results? According to the manual, `tail -cNUM shows the last NUM bytes of a file`. So, I'm curious why `echo 987654321 | tail -c3` in the terminal prints `21`.

Comment: Does the file end in a linefeed? The output of `echo` does.

Comment: There is no linefeed in the file. Maybe the output of echo ending with a linefeed can account for the result of 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `echo` appends a newline character (\n) to the output. When you pipe the output of `echo 987654321` to `tail -c3`, it processes the string `987654321\n`.

If you don't want the `echo` command to append a newline character, you can use the `-n` flag:

```
echo -n 987654321 | tail -c3 # outputs 321
```

**Note:** The `-n` flag in the echo command is not part of the POSIX standard i.e. some implementations of `echo` may not support the `-n` flag. So as mentioned by *@Biffen*, using the `printf` command is recommended, which is more portable and adheres to the POSIX standard. Something like:

```
printf "987654321" | tail -c3
```

Comment: Also, the lack of a line feed at the end of your test file violates the POSIX definition of a "text file".